# How do I program a for loop that goes from 0-108 every multiple of 9.

Tags: java

How do I create a for loop with multiples of 9 from 0-108. 
This is where i am so far:

```
public class Ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            for(int n = 0; n <= 108; n=n%9){
                System.out.println(n);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost right. Change `n=n%9` to `n=n+9` and it'll work.

Comment: You don't need to use the remainder operator there, you can just increment `n` by 9.

Answer (score 4):

Simply increment n by 9 every loop

```
public class Ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            for(int n = 0; n <= 108; n+=9){ // n+=9 is shorthand for n=n+9
                System.out.println(n);
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:
n=n%9 will cause your loop to run forever. The value of n will **always** be 0 as 0%9 = 0

Comment: It would be helpful for you to explain why OP's current loop runs infinitely.

Comment: @Trobbins I hadn't even checked if his code ran, and nowhere did he mention errors. I was just showing that you can increment your counter however you want in the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 108 / 9; i++)
    System.out.println(i * 9);
```

Your solution will result in an infinite loop since you never change your *n* value.
You are using the module sign, which is the remainder of the division.

```
10 / 3 = 3
10 % 3 = 1 (since 10 - 9 = 1)
```

Since your *n* starts as zero, and you are saying: n = 0 % 9, n stays 0.

Comment: @Turtle: for no specific reason to be honest, I just prefer working like this, feels cleaner